# add_rewrite_rule show wrong template

Tags: wordpress, templates, url-rewriting, custom-post-type

I created rewrite_rule to my cpt (custom post type) tvshow.

my code:

```
function setup_new_var() {
   // Ensures the $query_vars['episode'] is available
   add_rewrite_tag( '%episode%', '([^&]+)' );
   
   add_rewrite_rule( 'tvshow/([^/]+)/episode/([^/]*)/?', 
    'index.php?post_type=tvshow&postname=$matches[1]&episode=$matches[2]', 'top' );
}
add_action( 'init', 'setup_new_var', 1);
```

and when i go to `domain.com/tvshow/show-name/` it shows tv-show single-post template as it supposed to .

But when i go to : `domain.com/tvshow/show-name/episode/episode-name/`
wordpress load the tv-show archive template.

where did i do wrong?

Comment: Did you do flush_rewrite_rules()?

Comment: @BorisVolkovich yes i did..